# The quotient value of the reciprocal of a fraction from the fraction quotient value

Tags: fractions

Say 
$$c = \frac{a}{b}$$ and 
$$f = \frac{b}{a}$$

where $a, b , c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{R}$

$c = $ quotient

$f = $ quotient of the reciprocal of a fraction

Is there any relationship between $c$ and $f$? Is it possible to find the quotient of the reciprocal of a fraction from the quotient of the fraction?

Comment: Well, quite clearly $c=\frac{1}{f}$ ...

Comment: is there a proof to this? @MattiP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we multiply $c$ by $f$, we get
$$
cf = \left(\frac{a}{b} \right) \left(\frac{b}{a} \right) = \frac{ab}{ba} = \frac{ab}{ab}
$$
Assuming that $b\neq 0$ and $a\neq 0$, this can be simplified to
$$
cf = 1
$$
And therefore we have a relation between the two. This can be rewritten as
$$
c = \frac{1}{f} \qquad \text{or, equivalently,} \qquad f = \frac{1}{c}
$$